# How to use built-in services from angularjs directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm able to get some **ID** from URL using angularjs built-in `$location` service. Now, I need to call a service with that ID when the page loads, and then response needs to be rendered in some way.

I'm using ng-init like:

```
ng-init="uid=$location.path().substring($location.path().lastIndexOf('/') + 1); callToTheService(uid);"
```

When I execute, this way ng-init is not be able to call the built-in service and that's why I'm getting undefined. What is that I'm missing in AngularJS? I've to configure it in the exact way.

Comment: I've to store that ID into a list, and pass that list through functions. I can't define the list in $scope.

Comment: The list has to be object, So that later I can append service data.

Comment: @S.Negi once again.. Initialise `$scope.object = {};`, Populate: `$scope.object.list = [];`, Append: `$scope.object.list.push($scope.uid);`, Store: `YourService.store($scope.object);`, Populate data from service: `$scope.object.data = YourService.getData();`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey let me try, But I've bindings based on that list. I'm afraid that might not work with the change.

Comment: @S.Negi you would need to describe it slightly better. What are those bindings doing to the list, and what changes are applied? (if you don't want your list to be modified, use its copy instead: `$scope.list_copy = angular.copy($scope.object.list);`)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey well, I did mentioned a part. aologies for that, and for list it has objects, nested objects, and arrays. All of it binds to the view.

Comment: @S.Negi sounds like JSON. As long as you bind it to the scope, it will work as intended. So how does `uid` get into this picture?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey based on the uid from URL, I need to validate the data on the view as soon as controller loads.

Comment: Instead of initializing code using ng-init, I implemented the below answer with few changes. This has been resolved now so closing this, and finally thanks to @AlekseySolovey for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to initialise it in the controller. Simply bind it to scope. Then Inject your service and call a function from it. Here is an example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $location, YourService) { // injections are important 
  $scope.uid = $location.path().substring($location.path().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  $scope.log = function() {
    YourService.callToTheService($scope.uid);
  }
});

app.service("YourService", function() {
  this.callToTheService = function(uid) {
    console.log("UID: ",uid); // empty in this case
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="log()">Log UID</button>
</div>
```